# bash script for systemctl list-units --type service on Centos

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script with the following line:
systemctl list-units --type service, and my script is stuck and and I want  to run on without pressing the space key.
How can i proceed to have the same output for the command without pressing the space key?
Basically the script must to move one without asking me to press the space bar.
Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Add `--no-pager` to `systemctl` if you do not wish to see the pager:

```
systemctl --no-pager list-units --type service
```

or alternatively redirect the output to something that is not a terminal.

```
systemctl list-units --type service | cat
```